# Can't submit a form in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an app where the user must input details about themselves in a form;

```
        <ul class = 'rounded'>

            <li style = "color: #FFFFFF"><input type = "text" placeholder = "Name" name = "name" id = "name" autocapitalize = "on" autocorrect = "off" autocomplete = "off" style="color: #FFFFFF;  background: transparent url(../.png);  border: 0;  font: normal 17px Helvetica;  padding: 0;  display: inline-block;  margin-left: 0px;  width: 100%;  -webkit-appearance: textarea;" /></li>
            <li style = "color: #FFFFFF"><input type = "email" placeholder = "Email" name = "email" id = "email" autocapitalize = "off" autocorrect = "off" autocomplete = "off" style="color: #FFFFFF;  background: transparent url(../.png);  border: 0;  font: normal 17px Helvetica;  padding: 0;  display: inline-block;  margin-left: 0px;  width: 100%;  -webkit-appearance: textarea;" /></li>
            <li style = "color: #FFFFFF"><input type = "text" maxlength = "11" placeholder = "Telephone" name = "telephone" id = "telephone" style="color: #FFFFFF;  background: transparent url(../.png);  border: 0;  font: normal 17px Helvetica;  padding: 0;  display: inline-block;  margin-left: 0px;  width: 100%;  -webkit-appearance: textarea;" /></li><br>

            <li>Notifications<span class = 'toggle'><input type = 'checkbox' class = 'toggle' name = 'notifications' id = 'notifications' /></span></li>
            <li>Preview<span class = 'toggle'><input type = 'checkbox' class = 'toggle' name = 'preview' id = 'preview' /></span></li>

            <li>Set Profession</li>

            <select name = 'job' id = 'job'>
                <option value = 'jobselect'>Select Profession</option>
                <option value = 'job1'>Mechanical Engineer</option>
                <option value = 'job2'>Software Engineer</option>
                <option value = 'jobother'>Other</option>
            </select>

            <p style = 'font-weight: normal; color: white;'>If you chose 'Other', please specify: <input type = "text" placeholder = "Other" name = "other" id = "other" autocapitalize = "on" autocorrect = "off" autocomplete = "off" style="color: #777;  background: transparent url(../.png);  border: 0;  font: normal 17px Helvetica;  padding: 0;  display: inline-block;  margin-left: 0px;  width: 100%;  -webkit-appearance: textarea;"/></p>

        </ul>

    </form>
```

and then after a button to submit it. the form is linked to a .js file coded as below

```
 var jQT = $.jQTouch({

icon: 'kilo.png',
statusBar: 'black'
```

});

```
 $('#settingsForm').submit(function() {

    var formValues = {
        'name' : document.getElementById('#name'),
        'email' : document.getElementById('#email'),
        'telephone' : document.getElementById('#telephone'),
        'notifications' : document.getElementtById('#notifications'),
        'preview' : document.getElementById('#preview'),
        'job' : document.getElementById('#job'),
        'other' : document.getElementById('#other')
    };

    var formValueStr = JSON.stringify(formValues);

    $.cookie('SettingsCookie', formValueStr, { expires: 14 });
```

});

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var formValueStr = $.cookie('SettingsCookie');

    if (formValueStr != null) {

        var formValues = JSON.parse(formValuesStr);

        write(formValues['#name']);
        write(formValues['#email']);
        write(formValues['#telephone']);
        write(formValues['#notifications']);
        write(formValues['#preview']);
        write(formValues['#job']);
        write(formValues['#other']);

    }
```

});

but something had gone wrong and i can't figure out what. the form isn't dsaved as it is supposed to be and the information in the fields is deleted when i want it to stay. how can i fix it? any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing your opening `<form id="settingsForm">` tag..

as you are working with JQuery you better use `$('#name').val();` instead

This is for the select list.. you basicly have to loop all the elements of the select list and check them if they are selected or not.

```
  <select name="garden" multiple="multiple">

    <option>Flowers</option>
    <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
    <option>Trees</option>
    <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>

    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Dirt</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
<script>

    $("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          $("div").text(str);
        })
        .trigger('change');
</script>
```

and on your example..

```
<script>
   var changedValues = [];
   $("select#job option:selected").each(function () {
             changedValues.push($(this).text());
    });

</script>

<select name = 'job' id = 'job'>
                <option value = 'jobselect'>Select Profession</option>
                <option value = 'job1'>Mechanical Engineer</option>
                <option value = 'job2'>Software Engineer</option>
                <option value = 'jobother'>Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ok i did open the form i just didn't copy it over by mistake. and i had $('#name').val(); before and i was told to change it becasue it didn't save the selection list selection and the state of the toggle buttons. do you know how to save them with jQuery?

Comment: it stil won't work - every time i leave the page the data is forgotten

Comment: did you test if your cookie is made in your browser?

Comment: i'm confused. what? i changed the .js file to have the $('#name').val(); etc

Comment: Yes, are you 100% sure the data is stored in the cookie, are you sure the cookie is even created? If there is no cookie you can't get the info in first place.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `document.getElementById('name').value` to read text value in java script.

Comment: so instead of write(formValue...) i put your line of code in for each of the lines i had?

Comment: var formValues = {
        'name' : document.getElementById('name').value,
        'email' : document.getElementById('email').value,
        'telephone' : document.getElementById('telephone').value,
        'notifications' : document.getElementtById('notifications').value,
        'preview' : document.getElementById('preview').value,
        'job' : document.getElementById('job').value,
        'other' : document.getElementById('other').value
    };
and then remove # while set in cookie may be it worked out.

Comment: that's broken my app - now nothing is being shown except a black screen

Answer (score -1):

I just had a very similar issue. I had a CheckBox that wasn't appearing when other people used it, it was sometimes OK with IE8 on XP but not on IE9 or Windows 7 or Firefox. Eventually i tracked it down to name="preview". If i changed the name to "asdpreview" or even "review" it was fine.

I haven't been able to figure out exactly why there's an issue - maybe "preview" is now reserved? Anyhow changing the name might fix your problem too.